# matching groupmembers against another group and add its name to the first

Tags: mysql

i need to take the members of each group in table_a and look in table_b if there is one or more groups with exact same members if so ad the resulting groupnames to the result.

table_a holds groupmembers:

`+-------+----------+--------+-------+ 
|uniqeid|objectname|property|value  |
+-------+----------+--------+-------+
|0      |thing1    |color   |grey   |
+-------+----------+--------+-------+
|1      |thing1    |hardness|100    |
+-------+----------+--------+-------+
|2      |thingy    |sofness |80     |
+-------+----------+--------+-------+
|3      |thingy    |color   |brown  |
+-------+----------+--------+-------+
|4      |thingy    |emits   |gas    |
+-------+----------+--------+-------+
|5      |item      |exists  |1      |
+-------+----------+--------+-------+`

continues with endless data like this with all kinds of propertys and objectnames.

table_b is basicaly the same but it holds objecttypes for the groups in table_a

`+-------+----------+---------+ 
|uniqeid|objecttype|property |
+-------+----------+---------+
|0      |stone     |color    |
+-------+----------+---------+
|1      |stone     |hardness |
+-------+----------+---------+
|2      |stuff     |softness |
+-------+----------+---------+
|3      |stuff     |color    |
+-------+----------+---------+
|4      |stuff     |emits    |
+-------+----------+---------+`

continues with truckloads of data.

now i would like to make a view table  out of that that would look like this:

`+----------+--------------------+------------+ 
|objectname|propertys           |objecttype  |
+----------+--------------------+------------+ 
|thing1    |color,hardness      |stone       |
+----------+--------------------+------------+
|thingy    |softness,color,emits|stuff       |
+----------+--------------------+------------+
|item      |exists              |NULL        |
+----------+--------------------+------------+`

for an object to become a certain type the exact propertys must be there on both sides,duplicate propertys schould be ignored.

this should be done in mysql only.

i tryd it with matching two groupconcats against each other but faild,
and views dont like subquerys.

greets

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your attempted query, even if it doesn't work? It will help others better understand your question and your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way would be to join on the list of properties.

Fortunately, mysql has the [`group_concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function that can produce such a list, and which can be made to produce a list of unique, consistently ordered elements suitable for comparison:

```
select
    objectname,
    a.propertys,
    group_concat(objecttype) objecttypes
from (select objectname,
    group_concat(distinct property order by property) propertys
    from table_a
    group by 1) a
left join (select objecttype,
    group_concat(distinct property order by property) propertys
    from table_b
    group by 1) b
on a.propertys = b.propertys
group by 1, 2
```

The *left* join is what gives you the null in the last column if there's no match.

Comment: iget an #1054 - Unknown column 'a.property' in 'field list'

Comment: the only problem now is a thing that matches more than one objecttype gets a new row insted of objecttype,objecttype.

Comment: you didn't say you wanted objecttypes to be a list too, and your example data and sample output don't have it either - we are not mind readers. Nevertheless, I have fixed the query to do that too.